# Curve is deforming the object weirdly

Tags: modeling, curve-modifier

My curve modifier is deforming these ruffles strangely, one side is correct and one is is just completely inward..I tried using CTRL + A and then choose rotation and scale but it doesn't work. I tried everything I can

[image]

Comment: If you don't mind sharing, can you upload your .blend file to https://pasteall.org/blend/ ? Thanks.

Comment: Here you go

[.blend](https://pasteall.org/media/1/e/1e44efac2dd557d55ee01d56b5988849.blend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each handle/vertex of a curve has a tilt value. This can be seen in the Transform info menu.

[image]

A good way of editing multiple tilt values instead of editing them one by one from that menu is, activate proportional editing with the <kbd>O</kbd> key or clicking the button near the Snapping option, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Use scrollwheel to change the size of the area of effect.

[image]

Comment: I know I have accepted you answer but I wanted to ask if there is any other way to fix this? Because when I treid other objects with other shapes of curves, it works just fine.

Comment: I don't actually know. I'm assuming you only get this when you convert a mesh to curve? Maybe that's blenders best guess what the normals should be. Just guessin'